# Laravel: pagination limit the number using dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I have a page which contain a table to display a list of users from the database and i used pagination to display only 10 users per page how i can change the number of users depend on the number selected by dropdown menu for example in the link below the second table contain "Show  entries" which needed here. so can i pass the value from selected item to controller or there is a different way to do that ?
https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/pages/tables/data.html

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/adAkyK

Comment: Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and specifically how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make a variable which will hold the pageinate data, suppose you are sending through ajax, use the pageinateData and in your controller you can call something like this:

```
$users = App\User::paginate($request->pageinateData);
```

So every time you can call with this data set.

**EDIT:**

In your controller you can do something like this:

```
public function pUserList(Request $request) {
    $data = [];
    $data['users'] = App\User::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate($request->pageinateData);


    return view('userlist', $data);
}
```

`$this` will give you errors.
You can use on `change` in jquery to get the values

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#issueinput5').on('change', function() {
    alert($('#issueinput5').val());
    $.ajax({
        url:'your url here',
        method:'POST',
        data:{'pageinateData':$('#issueinput5').val(),},
        success:function(d){
         // Do your code...
        }
   });
  });
});
```

**Edit 2:**

For the `csrf_token` you need to do the following: add to your html headers

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and in ajax call you need to have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#issueinput5').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'/lists/user',
        method:'POST',
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        data:{'pageinateData':$('#issueinput5').val(),},
        success:function(d){
          console.log(d)
        }
   });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry i said dropdown menu but i mean select field. How i can sent variable or value from select to controller ?

<select id="issueinput5" name="priority" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-title="Priority">
          <option value="low">Low</option>
          <option value="medium">Medium</option>
          <option value="high">High</option>
         </select>

Comment: So i need to use a form post in order to send the data to controller. right ?

Comment: You just need the value calculated even if changes and this will be sent through ajax, its better to assign the change into a variable and pass that variable into every ajax call.

Comment: I have add the select inside form tag but still the same error

Comment: I will do some test and comeback later

Comment: I've updated the controller part, there is a mistake in that also, please go through this.

Comment: Sorry for late replay after a lot of test don't know i can make it and this is my full source code  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B90HFm0P2IoXdHpvTnlJVW1xdWs

Comment: @fahadaldaferi give me some time. I'll review and let you know. Not able to view through my phone.

Comment: I mean which file?

Comment: userlist.blade.php  url is localhost/lists/user

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155135/discussion-between-nitish-kumar-and-fahad-aldaferi).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#issueinput5').on('change',function(){
       $.ajax({
        url:'supply your url here',
        method:'POST',
        data:{'priority':$(this).val(),},
        success:function(d){
          console.log(d)
        }
       });
      })
    })
```